# Apache Drill: Local udf directory must be writable for application user error

Tags: bash, apache-drill

I'm trying to get Drill up and running on my machine. However, whenever I enter drill-embedded mode (bin/drill-embedded on Bash), I get this error:

```
 Error: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Local udf directory [/tmp/drill/udf/udf/local] must be writable for application user (state=,code=0)
```

If I try to run a query at this point, it'll give back:

```
No current connection
```

Any idea how to fix this? I've tried starting with a clean shell with no luck. Is it a permissions issue?

Comment: Is `/tmp/drill/udf/udf/local` writable by the user you are executing this command with?

Comment: It certainly reads exactly like a permissions issue

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the directory `/tmp/drill/udf/udf/local` write access. Since it is a directory in `/tmp`, you might need root access to give permissions, or you will have to use `sudo`. To give permission, use this:

```
chmod 777 -R /tmp/drill/udf/udf/local
```

Also make sure the user is having at least read permission on the parent directories, otherwise you will get a permission denied error again.